# Firestore query not successful

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

From [firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) it is okay to query documents like this:

```
citiesRef.whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
    .whereGreaterThan("population", 1000000);
```

But my task is not successful when I try to implement it.

This is my code

```
db.collection("needs")
            .whereEqualTo("topic", topic)
            .whereLessThan("expiresAt", currentTimeStamp)
            //.orderBy("expiresAt",  Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            //.startAt(ts)
            //.limit(35)
            .get(source)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    Needs need;
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            need = document.toObject(Needs.class).withId(document.getId());
                            needs.add(need);
                            mAdapter.setData(needs);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error getting Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you really need to pass source in get()? If yes, then check it's value.

Comment: source is from server `Source source = Source.SERVER;`

Comment: So to understand better you are getting `Error getting Data` message right? Have you tried to use `Needs need = document.toObject(Needs.class)` without `.withId(document.getId())`?

Comment: Yes I have, I believe I am getting the error because `!task.isSuccessful()`, and with the documentation, I am doing the right thing

Comment: "I am getting the error", what is the error? Paste it over here and please responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

It has been solved, we created an Index for the values we are using to query in firebase console